# how to change style display background image url

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 function btnclick() {

 var btn = document.getElementById('M_menucol').style.display;
 
 if (btn == 'none')
 {
     document.getElementById('M_menucol').style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById('M_menubtn').style.backgroundImage = "url(.../image/cancel.png)";

 }
 else {
     document.getElementById('M_menucol').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('M_menubtn').style.backgroundImage = "url(.../image/menubtn.png)";

 }



 };
```

i want change display none to block and reverse + backgroundimage url
display change is working but background image change dont working
plz give me solution...
sorry for my bad english

I'm sorry my meaning was that when I click the button it opens a menu, and the button's image changes. Clicking the button again closes the menu and returns the image to its original state.

And I will study hard ;)

https://jsfiddle.net/phnzb10m/12/

Comment: In what case the `btn` variable will be equal to 'none' string? To change style of an object you can just toggle a class of the element: like `btn.classList.toggle('cancel')`. In CSS define the background styles by default and with `cancel` class. And you should probably start your learning of HTML, CSS and JS from very beginning)

Comment: thanks for your reply Leonid. I think you mean add cancel to class and use toggle. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote the name of the class whose background needs to be changed...

Comment: If your element will not be displayed, why would it have a background-imag? It won't be displayed at all. Changing the background-image will do nothing here.

Comment: I wrote it stupidly and edited it, can you read it again?

Comment: Just add the part of DOM you are trying to manipulate with. And add some true images for background please. something we can operate with.

Comment: I tried adding images and code! 

It's my first time doing it, it's amazing

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this:

```
function btnclick() {

    var btn = document.getElementById('M_menucol');

    if(btn != null) {
        btn.classList.toggle("cancel")
    }
};
```

The style.css file would contain something like this:

```
#M_menucol{
    display: none;
    background-image: url(.../image/menubtn.png);
}
.cancel{
    display: block;
    background-image: url(.../image/cancel.png);
}
```

Comment: Meaning something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/8b2nadou/

Answer (score 0):

1. In your fiddle why do you separated `col`, `btn` with comma when you setting the style of them ? i think you mean semicolon instead
2. In your fiddle the element id is `Mmenubtn` while you write it `M_menubtn` in the script
3. you should know that `style` is an object of elements so it's cannot output the style sets by `style` or `link` tags it's just output inline style or style sets to it by js
4. if you want to get style sets by `style` or `link` tags you will be need to use `getComputedStyle()` method

- by default when there's no any inline style the values of `style` object properties is empty string so you can check if it's return empty string or `none` then execute you script

1. **By Display Property**

```
    function btnclick() {
      var col = document.getElementById('M_menucol');
      var btn = document.getElementById('M_menubtn');

      if (col.style.display === "" || col.style.display == 'none') { 
            col.style.display = 'block'
            btn.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://postimg.cc/68V0PW0t)";
      } else { 
            col.style.display = 'none'
            btn.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://i.postimg.cc/vBVMcpmM/menubtn.png)";
      }
    }
```

2. **By getComputedStyle() Method**

```
    function btnclick() {
      var col = document.getElementById('M_menucol');
      var btn = document.getElementById('M_menubtn');

      if (getComputedStyle(col, null).display == 'none') { 
            col.style.display = 'block';
            btn.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://postimg.cc/68V0PW0t)";
      } else { 
            col.style.display = 'none';
            btn.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://i.postimg.cc/vBVMcpmM/menubtn.png)";
      }
    }
```